# WooCommerce: hook when saving changes to product in an order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, action, hook

I have been searching for hours...

I can't figure out how get a function to be executed when clicking "save" after editing the quantity of a product in an existing order.

I tried this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_edit_product', 'your_function_name');
function your_function_name(){
//my php function code would be here
}
```

but the your_function_name function is not being called when clicking save.

I tested the function and when calling it directly it works as it should, so I think I got the wrong hook...

Comment: - were you doing this from the admin side or the live side? - if live side... from the cart?

Comment: Admin side, when viewing the order details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

after wrestling with this issue for 2 days now, i found it: there is two hooks, one before and one after saving:

1. woocommerce_before_save_order_items
2. woocommerce_saved_order_items

both are fired when saving an order in the backend. one before the save and one afterwards.

both two hooks carry the same variables: $order_id (int) & $items (array)

i guess with the first hook, you could get the old order and compare its contents with the items array to see what has changed. at least this is what i try to accomplish now.

so this is how you would trigger this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_save_order_items', 'so42270384_woocommerce_before_save_order_items', 10, 2 );
function so42270384_woocommerce_before_save_order_items( $order_id, $items ) {
    echo $order_id;
    var_dump( $items );
}
```

### be aware..

adding a product to an exitsting order does implement another hook that gets called before this (so when hitting SAVE, the above function will fire, but the order and its items are already set BEFORE saving (when adding a product, the order will save immediately). that means `$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );` will have the new items already in it, before and after, so there is no way to find, what has changed.). but the `woocommerce_ajax_add_order_item_meta` hook is triggered on 'add product' and helped me on that end. happy coding everyone..

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log. Should be some info there. If I am looking at the correct action it takes four arguments:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_order_edit_product', $this->id, $item_id, $args, $product );
```

So your code should be:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_edit_product', 'your_function_name', 10, 4);
function your_function_name($id, $item_id, $args, $product){
//my php function code would be here
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the error_log... I tried it with and without the 2 extra arguments, both ways the 'your_function_name' function is not being triggered. 'your_function_name' does not need any arguments, it's just a test function to see if it get's triggered at all.

Comment: Sorry. Was wrong about how add_action works. Apparently you can omit the arguments. So ignore my answer...