# WooCommerce: Trouble with priority in woocommerce_saved_order_items

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook

I have some trouble with the priority in the hook woocommerce_saved_order_items

In the order, I have a custom field as meta of the order. When I click save, it is stored as meta information.

Now, I have a plugin which hooks into woocommerce_saved_order_items. The hook is

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_saved_order_items', array( $this, 'synchronize_events' ), 40, 1 );
```

But when this hook is executed, my custom field is not yet stored or updated as meta, so this hook doesn't get the new updated information. I tried to set the priority higher to 999, so maybe it will be executed later, but that doesn't work either.

Is there a hook which comes later than woocommerce_saved_order_items, so I can be sure that my custom field is stored? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This seems to be a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202672/woocommerce-hook-when-saving-changes-to-product-in-an-order

Comment: Hi @7uc1f3r, I already fount that post. It says that woocommerce_saved_order_items is triggered after saving - but then, I ask myself why my change is not considered? I always have to click 2 times on save so that my changed meta is considered in the above action hook.