# WooCommerce: hook for admin edited orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good morning. I have a single custom function which should be triggered when:

1. an order is created or modified from frontend
2. an order is created or modified from backend (admin mode), in any way: refunds, products added or removed, coupon applied, order notes inserted, order action changed, etc.

In the 1st case I'm using `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'calcolo_corrispettivi', 10, 1)`. Works fine.

In the 2nd case I've tried using `add_action('save_post', 'calcolo_corrispettivi', 10, 1)`. It crashes when triggered by non "order" type posts.

Full code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'calcolo_corrispettivi', 10, 1);
add_action('save_post', 'calcolo_corrispettivi', 10, 1);

// Not enough for all possible 'edit' actions:
// add_action('woocommerce_order_refunded', 'calcolo_corrispettivi', 10, 1);

function calcolo_corrispettivi ( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_refunds = $order->get_refunds();
    $totale_EP = 0;
    $totale_altri = 0;
    
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $prodotto = $item->get_product();
        $editrice = $prodotto->get_attribute('pa_casa-editrice');
        
        if ($editrice == "EP") {
            $totale_EP = $totale_EP + $item->get_subtotal() - $order->get_total_refunded_for_item( $item_id );
        } 
        else {
            $totale_altri = $totale_altri + $item->get_subtotal() - $order->get_total_refunded_for_item( $item_id );
        }
    }
        
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'totale_EP', $totale_EP);
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'totale_altri', $totale_altri);
}
```

Is there any specific woocommerce hook for admin updated orders?

Thank you.

---

**Update.** I've also tried using `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta`, as suggested below, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647343/woocommerce-hook-for-order-update). The solution works *only if* I press "Update" button under "Order action":

[Admin order edit page - Update button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6amf.png)

But, for instance, if I change the quantity of a product, the order gets updated without pressing the "Update" button, and so without running my custom function:

[Admin order edit page - Update single product quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYcri.png)

---

**Solution.** These hooks worked for me:

- Order modified by admin on backend page: `woocommerce_saved_order_items` (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42270384/8699721))
- Note added: `woocommerce_order_note_added`
- Refund: `woocommerce_order_refunded`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Woocommerce hook for order update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647343/woocommerce-hook-for-order-update)

Comment: Not completely: some changes are not hooked. Check my update.

Comment: Well changing the quantity of an order item, isn’t really order meta data, I suppose. You probably need to look into `woocommerce_order_item_quantity` or similar then.

Comment: Neither any of these actions is hooked: https://pasteboard.co/K7Wa4ag.png. A workaround could be to hook automatic order note updates: they are produced in every of these updates. But how?

Comment: @checkm _"Neither any of these actions is hooked"_. See META BOXES ORDER [Where to find a complete list of Javascript (JQuery) events that fire on the WooCommerce admin page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66626943/11987538). & https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/042582e022ab09c3773babc42d942003f551ab5a/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js In other words, those are ajax driven